# How can I record Shell script outputs to log file

Tags: shell-script, shell

My Shell script include series of steps for example 
first step

```
App=  read -p "### Please enter Application name " 
Env = read -p "### Enter Enviornment name (Dev,test)"
```

second step

```
cd /opt/Weblogic/
mkdir $App
mkdir $Env
```

Third Step

```
cp /tmp/weblogic/* /opt/weblogic/$App/$Env/*
```

So my question is how can I record what user is entering each time? Is there a way I can store the user the whole input and output to something call `temp.txt`? This way I can review to find out which user has enterred which input.

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap it all in a subshell and `tee` or `tee -a` to output to `temp.txt`.

e.g.

```
(
read -p "### Please enter Application name " App
read -p "### Enter Enviornment name (Dev,test)" Env
echo "App: $App"
echo "Env: $Env"

cd /opt/Weblogic/
mkdir $App
mkdir $Env

cp /tmp/weblogic/* /opt/weblogic/$App/$Env/*

) | tee -a temp.txt
```

The `-a` on `tee` will append to the `temp.txt` for each execution. You can remove it if you want it to start fresh each time.